# Blocking all connections to a specific domain only

Tags: ios, swift, networkextension

I've been struggling to find how I could potentially implement a simple (iOS) app that would be able to block all connections to a specific domain (to prevent the user from accessing a specific social media platform for example, even from another app).

The information that I have found so far is that I should probably create a Packet Tunnel Provider within a Network Extension and ask the user to add VPN configurations, but I haven't found any example code that would show exactly how to implement this.

Do you have any idea how I could do that in a simple way (block all connections to a specific domain)? Is there a framework/library that I could use to do it easily?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well Apple has provided Network Extension from WWC 2015. it is very simple to implement

1. Create Xcode project
2. Follow steps in attached image and type **Network Extension**

[image]

in signing & capabilities at the bottom a capability has been added with the name of **Network Extension** make sure to mark check **Content Filter ** and **Packet Tunnel**

[image: Network Extension Capabilities]

you're done with the basic setup. to verify go to your project structure and there 2 targets/folders has been added with the name of **PacketTunnelProvider** & **FilterDataProvider**

Please review for further assistance

1. VPN Configuration and setup can be found here
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/routing_your_vpn_network_traffic
2. PackTunnelProvider Configuration can be found here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/packet_tunnel_provider
3. Content Filtration can be found here
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/content_filter_providers

**Note:** for testing you require a physical device (iPhone/iPad) as Simulators will not work for testing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it would not be easy, but you can do it.

Sample code from Apple could be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimpleTunnel/Introduction/Intro.html) and [here](https://github.com/ios-sample-code/SimpleTunnel). This project is for iOS, but it may be on deprecated Swift version, so you will need to do some work to launch it now.

The part you are interested in the SimpleTunnel sample is FilterDataProvider and FilterControlProvider, other things you can omit, because the purpose of this sample is to demonstrate a lot of abilities.

There is also a [sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/filtering_network_traffic) for macOS that is more focused on your needs, and macOS SDK is alike to iOS, but less powerful.

You may want to see [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/714) video to sort things up in mind.

There are a lot of firewalls solutions for ios and mac, and some of them are [opensource](https://github.com/confirmedcode/Lockdown-iOS)

The part you are interested in the SimpleTunnel sample is FilterDataProvider and FilterControlProvider, other things you can omit, because the purpose of this sample is to demonstrate a lot of abilities.

You will need a developer account, a network extension capability assigned to an application identity, and proper network extension entitlement file a to run things up.
There is a way to sign it manually for development without account&capability, but to distribute you will need it anyway.

For some restrictions you may be needed to install MDM profile on the device.